# Parent class cannot access local variables in child class's file

Tags: python, inheritance, scope, sympy

I have a class `TransferFunction` in `transfer_function.py`

```
class TransferFunction(ABC):
    def __init__(self, tf):
        self.__domain = 's'
        self.__F = tf
        self.__f = sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(tf, s, t, noconds=True)
        self.__tf = tf
```

And I inherit this class to `controller.py`

```
import sympy
from transfer_function import TransferFunction


class ProportionalController(IController, TransferFunction):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._param = param
        super().__init__(param)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__} ({self._param})'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t, s = sympy.symbols('t, s')
    controller = ProportionalController(5)
    print(controller)
```

I expect it to print `Controller(5)` but instead I just got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Code\python_files\Controller-Simulation\controller.py", line 70, in <module>
    controller = ProportionalController(5)
  File "E:\Code\python_files\Controller-Simulation\controller.py", line 28, in __init__
    super().__init__(param)
  File "E:\Code\python_files\Controller-Simulation\transfer_function.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.__f = sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(tf, s, t, noconds=True)
NameError: name 's' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But when i copy the whole `TransferFunction` class to `controller.py`, everything runs properly as expected.
Why didn't it work in the first case though? And how do I solve this problem? Since as far as I know, importing a file is equivalent to moving everything from that file to the main file.

Comment: `t, s = sympy.symbols('t, s')` The s and t variables are defined by this line of code in `controller.py`.  Those variables are not defined anywhere in `transfer_function.py`.  Where are you expecting them to come from?

Comment: _Since as far as I know, importing a file is equivalent to moving everything from that file to the main file_ The line of code `if __name__ == '__main__'` specifically prevents the code underneath from running when that module is imported.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your help. Is there any way I can work this out?